# What is considered the parent() of a <span> in an <li>?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

In the example:

```
<ul>
<li>text <span>more text</span></li>
</ul>
```

I am wanting to remove the `<li>` by clicking on the `<span>` within the `<li>` with something like:

```
$(this).parent().remove()
```

What is considered the `parent()` of a `<span>` in an `<li>`?

**Solution**

The above code works so that does seem to be the case (ie that the `<li>` in this instance is the parent of the `<span>`).

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is like this

```
<ul>
    <li>text 
       <span class='delete_link'>more text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here `<li>` is the parent of `<span>`. So

```
$(".delete_link").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().remove()
});
```

Then the result is empty `<ul>`

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

without `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

Parent of the span is the li in which it is contained:-

Here is the working fiddle for this:-

http://jsfiddle.net/eH27D/

```
<ul>
<li>text <span id="my-span">more text</span></li>
</ul>
```

This is to get the parent and then remove it.

```
console.log($("#my-span").parent());
$("#my-span").parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `li` is the parent of `span`, the code you executed will remove `li` and its children (`span`).

Incase if you want to preserve `span` element.

Try this

```
var s = $('span').detach(); // detach it
$('ul').append(s);          // append it to ul
$('li').remove();           // then remove the li
```

Answer (score 0):

the **parent** of you **span** is **LI**

```
<ul>
<li>text <span id=span>more text</span></li>
</ul>
```

`$("#span").parent().remove();`

will remove the parent **li** of **span** and all his childs

so if you have

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <span id=span>more text</span>
         <span>more text</span>
         <span>more text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

applying :

```
$("#span").parent().remove();
```

will output :

```
<ul></ul>
```